# For unittest.TestCase subclass, unable to get class attribute when testcases are executed by run method

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, python-unittest

I want to set a value to a class attribute inside a test method and use the value with same class attribute in another test method. When I tried in normal way by executing test cases with `run` method, got error as `AttributeError: 'Unit' object has no attribute 'b'`. Anyway, I found other solutions by using `global` variable and one more by assigning the class to a variable. May I know the reason why I am not able to retrieve class attribute which I had set the same using another method? Also, could you help me explaining the actual process with `run` method... Thanks in advance.

Here is a sample code which I tried:

```
import unittest
class Unit(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_i(self):
        self.b=20
    def test_j(self):
        print self.b


suite=unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Unit)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
test_i (__main__.Unit) ... ok
test_j (__main__.Unit) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: test_j (__main__.Unit)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#52>", line 5, in test_j
AttributeError: 'Unit' object has no attribute 'b'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.078s

FAILED (errors=1)
<unittest.runner.TextTestResult run=2 errors=1 failures=0>


    #The two ways which I solved...
    #1.By Assinging class to a variable
 import unittest
 class Unit(unittest.TestCase):
         def test_i(self):
        Class=Unit
        Class.b=20
         def test_j(self):
    print self.b


suite=unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Unit)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
test_i (__main__.Unit) ... ok
test_j (__main__.Unit) ... 20
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.094s

OK
<unittest.runner.TextTestResult run=2 errors=0 failures=0>



#2.By using global attribute,but I need the class attribute value to be set and        retrieved

 import unittest
 class Unit(unittest.TestCase):
     def test_i(self):
     global b,
     b=20
     def test_j(self):
     print b


suite=unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Unit)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
test_i (__main__.Unit) ... ok
test_j (__main__.Unit) ... 20
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.063s

OK
<unittest.runner.TextTestResult run=2 errors=0 failures=0>
```

Answer (score 6):

The attribute does not appear in the instance because each test is executed in its own instance, as you can see in this code:

```
import unittest
class Unit(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('init!')
        super(Unit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def test_i(self):
        self.b = 20
    def test_j(self):
        print(self.b)

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Unit)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Which prints:

```
init!
init!
test_i (__main__.Unit) ... ok                                                                 
test_j (__main__.Unit) ... ERROR                                                              

======================================================================                        
ERROR: test_j (__main__.Unit)                                                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------                        
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                            
  File "prova.py", line 10, in test_j                                                         
    print(self.b)
AttributeError: 'Unit' object has no attribute 'b'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Notice the two "init!" at the beginning.

This is done because each test should not depend on the other tests.
There is a specific setup method, you should use it to set up the correct environment for your test.

If you want different set-ups then maybe you should consider splitting those tests in separate test cases.

Using a class variable or a global variable obviously works because the class is not deleted, and the globals are not cleared for every test.

On a side note:
The fact that the class is instantiated more times is quite clear in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code). As you can see, when they create the `TestSuite` they add each new test instantiating the class and passing the test name as parameter.
The `loadTestsFromTestCase` is simply a shortcut for creating a `TestSuite` in that way.